# Issues searching for a int

Tags: java, int

I'm trying to get the following code to compile,

```
public List<T> searchByInt(String int) {
    System.out.println("in searchByInt");
    return getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Userdetails.searchByInt").setParameter("id", "%" + int + "%").getResultList();
}
```

However, I am having issues with this section of code, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Please do not overgeneralize errors/problems with the word "issues". Please post the retrieved error message / exception message outright in the question. You should have gotten a compilation error `Syntax error on token "int", invalid VariableDeclaratorId` on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here is, that `int` is a reserved word, so you can't give any variable the name `int`. Another problem is, that you are not handling the variable like a `int`, because you basically renamed the variable. You can not add `"%"` to the int as this is a `String` and additionally this would not make any sense in the query, as the `%` in the other query is used as a String-wildcard.
Use the following code to search for the id:

```
public List<T> searchByInt(int id) {
    return getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Userdetails.searchByInt").setParameter("id", id).getResultList();
}
```